# How to download server files with only ftp link

Tags: ftp, download

So I have just started to work on a client's site, and their site is apparently on a hong kong based hosting company.

I asked them the username and password for accessing the files and their old developer gave us this ftp:/130.. ip address like link 
with the username and password.

When I click the link and the browser takes my username and password, I get a index list of all the files.

I however want to download all the files and I was wondering if there is a way of doing so without having the hosting site to have admin log in from. 
Just in case the hong kong office guys dont give in all the info.

What should I do to have the files download to a folder using something like Filezilla or some other method? Cause I am new to web development and design, I tried using filezilla but that didnt give me the directory or connect fully.

Answer (score 1):

the ftp user that gave u is limited . so with filezila you can see just a specific folder.

and in another hand , to download easily u can download them with IDM , just set user , pass into it and download all the files.
for id : http://www.internetdownloadmanager.com/support/using_idm/options.html
see **Site Logins tab** pasrt